# parsing huge xml

Tags: xml

I need to parse large XML Feeds (>100 mb) and persist into mysql database. XML files are well formatted and contain many child elements. I was thinking to use Java + XMLbeans and SAX to process the XML feeds and persist.

Please suggest me right approach to handle this case. I am worried about performance.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about once a while, daily or in files per second?

Comment: I don't think 100MB is that much, really. Why are you worried about performance if you're running it daily (and using Java)?

Comment: Are you worried about Java=XMLBeans mapping or XML parsing in general?

Comment: I want to know the approach for this case. Opting java + XMLBeans is the proper approach for parse and persist? Please let me know your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML to class object mapping is definitely the most easy to maintain and one of the sensible way to handle parse+persist problems. I'll suggest to check other solutions for XML mapping. Jibx comes to mind if you are looking for good performance. Please go through: [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-databdopt2/) before deciding. [**WARNING** : The article is ancient (2003) and may not reflect today's versions of the frameworks. Although you can use similar comparison to try out various options.]

XML Pull parsing is also a good (but obscure) option for very large XML files. (IMO 100MB is not that big.) Try to look at [XPP](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/) and [XML Pull Parsing](http://www.xmlpull.org/).  But this takes care of parsing only. However you can easily implement your own persist code over the pull parser. Maintaining such code is another story though.

Comment: Hi Elister,

Thank you for the detailed response. Will go with object mapping.

Answer (score 0):

please try this url which helps you better way...

```
http://simplepie.org/
http://github.com/rmccue/simplepie/downloads
```

Comment: It takes 30 seconds to read the FAQ and realize this isn't the right tool :P http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/can_simplepie_parse_raw_xml_feeds